# Azure Data Sync Error - Member Database is Read Only

Tags: sql, azure, data-synchronization, azure-data-sync

I have configured Azure Data Sync between our SQL on-prem and Azure SQL. Sync direction is to Hub (Azure) and conflict resolution is set to Member Win. Sync group has been configured successfully, and I have selected the tables I want to sync in the Hub (I synced schema previously using Data Migration). I have 83 tables that are selected for synchronization.

**Problem:** When starting the synchronization, I receive the following error:

> Database provisioning failed with the exception "SqlException Error Code: -2146232060 - SqlError Number:3906, Message: Failed to update database "*****" because the database is read-only. SqlError Number:2759, Message: CREATE SCHEMA failed due to previous errors.

Why would Data Sync be attempting to `CREATE SCHEMA` on my read-only on-prem instance, when I have configured it to synchronize in the other direction?

Appreciate any insight you can offer,

Cheers,

Answer (score -2):

You need to give dbowner access to role you are using with agent so that it can create a schema initially. It will create schema and tables with datasync.tablename that will have sync logs for respective table. If you sync 10 tables then 10 such tables will be created.